# Unable to save multiple Bitmaps with OutputStream/FileOutputStream in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-camera, crop

> **Currently,I'm having  double trouble.**

1. Unable to crop the Bitmap.
2. Unable to save multiple Bitmaps.

   Recently, I've made a camera app that saves the jpeg image to the SD card without any frail, however, I wanted to crop the Bitmap and save it as two parts (Save 2 images to the same folder). However, I'm unable to crop the bitmaps in my current code.

And the second problem is that I tested and tried to save the same bitmaps for testing purpose into the same folder by using FileOutputStreams but failed.(Actually I want to save the cropped version of the bitmap).

Everything seemed well, until now. Since I'm a noob I may be missing something or may have done some nonsense to my codes. I've put the codes (method) that I tried and failed.

```
public static void makeRotateImage(Activity activity, byte[] data, int maxPixel) {

        // This is the Original bitmap
        Bitmap bitmapSrc = makeTargetPixelImage(data, maxPixel);

        // get the degrees
        int degree = getCameraDisplayOrientation(activity);
        int destWidth = 0;
        int destHeight = 0;

        //alter or rotate
        if (degree % 180 == 0) {
            destWidth = bitmapSrc.getWidth();
            destHeight = bitmapSrc.getHeight();
        } else {
            destWidth = bitmapSrc.getHeight();
            destHeight = bitmapSrc.getWidth();
        }

        // Creating a new bitmap + I'm not sure but things are screwing up around here
        
        Bitmap bitmapDest = Bitmap.createBitmap(destWidth, destHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSrc, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    
        // creating the new canvas
        
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapDest);
        canvas.save();

        
        canvas.rotate(degree, destWidth / 2, destHeight / 2);
        int offset = (destHeight - destWidth) / 2 * ((degree - 180) % 180) / 90;
        canvas.translate(offset, -offset);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapSrc, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.restore();
        bitmapSrc.recycle();
        bitmapSrc = null;


        try {

        
            // Output the image to the path to the SD 
            
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(makeImagePath()));
            bitmapDest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
           
            OutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream(new File(makeImagePath()));
            bitmapDest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os2);
            os.close();
            os2.close();
           //croppedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's exactly the issue? doesn't compile, crash, other? By the way, never implement empty catch blocks, you'll never know if the exception is thrown. Especially when debugging. Also a Log.d() is better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually,there are no error but I'm unable to crop the from  Bitmap bitmapDest = Bitmap.createBitmap(destWidth, destHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); . As seen in the code I tried to output the 2 image with OutputStream but failed. I think instead of .close() I should use flush(). But anyway, my main problem is that I cannot crop the images.

Comment: Doesn't Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap, int, int, int, int)  work for you? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, int, int)